# Angular UI bootstrap progressbar minimum width

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to set the minimum width of the angular UI bootstrap progressbar. I checked the docs and they do not mention how to do this. I know for the 'regular' bootstrap you can use something like `style="min-width: 10em;"`. However this only works if you wrap it in the standard progress bootstrap divs like so:

```
<div class="progress">
    <uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active progress-bar" value="value" style="min-width: 10em;">
    <span> text </span></uib-progressbar>
</div>
```

But this displays a progressbar bar without the 'active' animation since regular bootstrap does not support this. When I try it like so it does not set the min-width property

```
<uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active progress-bar"value="value" style="min-width: 10em;">
    <span> text </span>
</uib-progressbar>
```

**edit:** I overlooked the animation section in the 'regular' bootstrap docs. I would however like to use the UI bootstrap progressbar if possible.

Comment: Sorry why do you say that regular bootstrap does not support animated progress bars? Here there's a demo of them: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular Bootstrap [supports](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-animated) animated progress bars.

Are you sure that you correctly imported Boostrap files? I think you might have included only the CSS file but not the JS. Take a look at the [basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) to see which files you should include.

Take also a look at the [uib-progressbar documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar). The code snippet you wrote seems to be correct. As I said, I think the reason for this problem is that you didn't include the JS file for Bootstrap.

---

EDIT: Oh, ui-bootstrap apparently doesn't need Bootstrap's JS, you're right.

Regarding the `min-width` part of your question: I noticed that you added the `progress-bar` class to the `<uib-progressbar>` element. According to the documentation, the `progress-bar` class should not be used (it will be added by ui-bootstrap to the `<div>` element that will be rendered *inside* `<uib-progressbar>`, and you can easily verify this by inspecting the progress bar width devtools).

Thus, the `min-width` property is to be applied to the *internal* `<div>`. However, since the rendering is managed by angular, the only way to change it is to add a CSS rule like this:

```
.setminwidth .progress-bar {
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

And then add the new `setminwidth` class to the external `<uib-element>` like this:

```
<uib-progressbar class="progress-striped setminwidth" value="22" type="warning">22%</uib-progressbar>
```

I tested this but it doesn't seem to work. I think it's because `min-width: 0;` [is hardcoded in the template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/8dc13be92469329605ca3dd73478cf7898a864ec), and it gets reset everytime ui-bootstrap re-renders the element.

I tried adding `!important` to the CSS rule, to avoid being overridden, but it doesn't work either.

I guess at this point you should consider why you need to add this `min-width` property, since ui-bootstrap likes to override it. Could it be because you don't want the progress bar to be "too empty" when the % is low? If that's the case, I think you should look up [the changes](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2511) recently introduced by Bootstrap: it seems that now they add a special `min-width` for 0%, 1% and 2%.

UPD: The Bootstrap folks apparently [changed their mind](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12848) and reverted the special `min-width` value. At this point, I think that ui-bootstrap should follow along and remove the hardcoded `min-width: 0;` as it's not needed anymore. I [just sent](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/5141) a pull-request to them. If they merge it, you will be able to use the CSS I posted above.

Comment: I made this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yiEUykZc7VUffKUywRRW?p=preview) . Look at the code for the second static progressbar. It does not properly set the minimum width. And using the bootstrap javascript is not a good practice as described [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together)

Comment: Thank you for submitting a pull request and getting to the bottom of this. I understand their reasoning why they changed the min-width property. I think I'll use black text instead.